# Mathematical operations over unicode numbers

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtable

I have created a simple JTable where some Persian strings and numbers are going to be entered through.

I have used some Persian fonts for the JTable and I can see the strings and numbers without any problem in the table, but as I have also used some mathematical operations in some columns of the table; unfortunately the JTable cannot recognize the Persian numbers; when I'm going to get the numbers from table model I get NumberformatException and the table model cannot identify them as numbers.

Any idea ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the answers to this question addresses your question:

- [Convert String to another locale in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java)

(The title is misleading ... it is really about converting Persian number strings to Java `int`s.)

---

I think that the `JTable` is a red herring.  AFAIK, `JTable` doesn't allow you to do "arithmetic operations" on regular number strings either.

Comment: Thanks Stephen C, This seems to be working, I will check it on later. You are right, but I get the value of specific columns cast them to double and then after the operation I set back the result value to the intended column.