# how to replace regex matches of an old array with new one in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex pattern:

```
'/(?:&#\d{2,4};)|(\d+[\.\d]*)|(?:[a-z](?:[\x00-\x3B\x3D-\x7F]|<\s*[^>]+>)*)|<\s*[^>]+>/i'
```

I want to replace array1 with array2 in any string, how can i replace the array1 elements with array2 elements using this regex?

```
String[] array1 = String[] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

String[] array2 = String[] {"۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹"};
```

Comment: ok... why do you use this regex for this? when do you want to replace it?

Comment: @micha I can use string.replace(). but I think using regex it is so faster!

Comment: @moallemi do you know what regex is and do you know what this pattern match and do you know for what regex is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want to convert Persian number to english...

Regex is not the best solution for this.
Look at this question : [Convert String to another locale in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java)

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(arabicToDecimal("۴۲"));
}

private static final String arabic = "\u06f0\u06f1\u06f2\u06f3\u06f4\u06f5\u06f6\u06f7\u06f8\u06f9";
private static String arabicToDecimal(String number) {
    char[] chars = new char[number.length()];
    for(int i=0;i<number.length();i++) {
        char ch = number.charAt(i);
        int index = arabic.indexOf(ch);
        if (index >= 0)
            ch = (char) (index + '0');
        chars[i] = ch;
    }
    return new String(chars);
}
```

Comment: I seems that the question assumed the opposite conversion: decimal to arabic.

Answer (score 2):

Well you don't need to use regex, or anything like this. You don't even need to use any special function.

```
String[] array1 = String[] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
```

Take a good look at this array. For your convenience `0` has index `0` , `1` has index `1` etc.

So you can do something like this, (pseudo - code):

```
foreach(char in stringToBeReplaced)
{
  if(char == an ASCII digit)
  {
     char = array2[array1.findIndexOf(char)];
  }
}
```

That's it. I 'll leave the details to you.