# Best way to convert English numbers to Arabic

Tags: java, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String to another locale in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java)

I want to convert a `java` `String` that contains english numbers to arabic one's so i make this

```
int  arabic_zero_unicode= 1632;
String str = "13240453";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i =0; i < str.length(); ++i ) {
    builder.append((char)((int)str.charAt(i) - 48+arabic_zero_unicode));
}

System.out.println("Number in English : "+str);
System.out.println("Number In Arabic : "+builder.toString() );
```

the out put

```
Number in English : 13240453
Number In Arabic : ١٣٢٤٠٤٥٣
```

is there another more efficient  way to do this ?

Comment: @5arx i saw this question . what i am trying to do here is to make the opposite , and for the question link you post , Integer.parse() make it i.e convert arabic to english number :)

Comment: @5arx Nope, this is the other way around.

Comment: You may desire to make sure that `str.charAt(i)` is a number, or this will create garbage for input such as `123,456.50'.

Comment: @Zéychin - you're correct, my bad. Apologies.

Comment: Not sure if you are aware of this, but your title is misleading.  We use Arabic numerals everywhere.

Comment: I tried to make it easy with this [light library](https://github.com/ALI-KH-Y/AnyNum).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This gives a 5x speedup over your version with a string of length 3036.
This also checks to make sure you're only changing digits. It's about a 6x speedup without the if/else check.

Please pardon me if the characters are incorrect/misplaced. I had to find some of them from another source.

```
char[] arabicChars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
    {
        builder.append(arabicChars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
System.out.println("Number in English : "+str);
System.out.println("Number In Arabic : "+builder.toString() );
```

Comment: I can not get the Arabic numbers to display in the right direction on Stackoverflow. They should be from `٠` to `٩`, not from `٩` to `٠`.

Comment: Persian chars would be 'char[] persianChars = {'۰', '۱', '۲', '٣', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '٩'};'

Comment: looks great and I use it in my project but i don't know why it throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: This works well, if you like also, you can add the Arabic comma to `arabicChars` array so it can be replaced when you have a number with double or float format. I will edit the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java doesn't throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: The solution works very well but screwed in decimals.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of Java classes that you can utilize to accomplish this in a high level fashion without explicit assumptions on Unicode table structure. For example you can check out [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html). However the idea will be the same as the code sample you've provided. The locale conversion methods or classes in Java library will only render the way numbers are displayed, they do not convert numeral symbols in a trivial way.