# Arabic Android phones shows latitude/longitude in Arabic localized numbers

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, arabic

Some Arabic Android phones show the latitude/longitude in Arabic numbers.

How can I capture the latitude/longitude values in English numbers in some Arabic phones?

sample:
location.longitude = "٣٥٫٠٠٢٣٨٨٣"

try to convert to this:
35.0023883

Thanks
Niz

Comment: The term **Natural numbers** has a specific meaning, regardless of locale, and I don't see how it applies here. What do you mean by Natural numbers?

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java#12568809