# How to show Arabic numbers retrieved from java method in xhtml

Tags: java, xhtml, numbers, ascii

I need your help in showing the Arabic numbers in xhtml page. Currently, I am getting the numbers in the xhtml page as (???? question mark) because when I am saving the below method in Jdeveloper, the Arabic numbers will be converted to question mark. This method will be converting the String of the English numbers to Arabic and its code is below:

```
String str ="";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
str = "1234566.555";
char[] arabicChars = {'٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'};

for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
{
    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
    {
        builder.append(arabicChars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
    }
    else
    {
        builder.append(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```

And the xhtml code is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
          xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
          xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
        <h:body> 
<h:outputText value="#{user1.builder}"/>
 </h:body>
 </html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: have you check this out `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java`

Comment: [Configuring JDeveloper to support UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17984_01/doc.898/e14693/appa_configuring_jdev.htm).

Comment: I will check both of them, but what is the way to code the arabic numbers as unicode

Comment: @primitiveType I need the vice versa which is converting english to arabic

Comment: @Phylogenesis no it is not serving my purpose

Comment: @99maas You say the source code is changing from Arabic numerals to `?` symbols. This is because JDeveloper is saving the file in a character set that does not contain Arabic numerals. You need to make sure JDeveloper is saving the files as UTF-8.

Comment: @Phylogenesis I got it now. Thanks

Comment: @primitiveType the link was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function is helpful for converting English numbers to Arabic:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
private String arabicDigits="";

public String arabicNumners(String englishNumber) {

String str=englishNumber;
char[] arabicChars = {'\u0660','\u0661','\u0662','\u0663','\u0664','\u0665','\u0666','\u0667','\u0668','\u0669'};

                                for(int i =0;i<str.length();i++)
                                {
                                    if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                                    {
                                        builder.append(arabicChars[(int)(str.charAt(i))-48]);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        builder.append(str.charAt(i));
                                    }
                                }
                                System.out.println("Number in English : "+str);
                                System.out.println("Number In Arabic : "+builder.toString() );



   return builder.toString();



}
```