# How to get Persian number from textfield and convert to double in Java?

Tags: java

How to convert "۱۲۳۴۵" Persian string numbers to double?

I want get Persian number from a textfield and save it in a double variable. I tried:

```
product.setSellPrice(Double.parseDouble(txtProductSalePrice.getText()));
```

but this throws `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:`.

Comment: So you want to convert a persian text to an decimal output. Search some library or do it youself, I dont believe java has a default library to do that.

Comment: This answer is useful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24407312/2413303

Comment: just mentioning this can help too http://stackoverflow.com/a/12568809/2930834

and deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could breakdown the String into chars and iterate through the characters using, for example, `toCharArray()` and then convert each number to its English equivalent.

```
String number = "";
for (char c : txtProductSalePrice.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == "۱") {
        number.concat("1");
        continue;
    }
    if (c == "۲") {
        number.concat("2");
        continue;
    }
    ....
}
return new BigDecimal(number).doubleValue();
```

I'm sure this could probably be improved though, and I'm not entirely sure whether `char` will support non-Roman letters.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) it's solve your problem. apply your precision-things to your text and this library do rest of things for you.

PS : you should use proper *Farsi* font