# Prevent change numbers localization when change android language localization

Tags: android

I want to change android application localization Arabic - English.
but when I change language to Arabic it's changed all numbers to Arabic so the app crashed I want to change language to Arabic and prevent change numbers language from English.

```
 Locale locale = new Locale(AppConfig.Language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = "ar";
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

when I want to use gps get location it's return numbers in arabic
how I can prevent it to change numbers language ??

Comment: Do you using font support arabic numbers? if yes, try without it.

Answer (score 22):

I know this answer is too late but it can help someone in the future.
I was struggling with it for some days but I found an easy solution.
just set the country as the second parameter.because some countries use Arabic numeral and others use the so-called Hindu Numerals

```
Locale locale = new Locale(LanguageToLoad,"MA");//For Morocco to use 0123...
```

or

```
Locale locale = new Locale(LanguageToLoad,"SA");//For Saudi Arabia to use ٠١٢٣...
```

Comment: How do you do this exactly? Locale locale = new Locale("ar","SA"); Locale.setDefault(locale); That did not work for me. The numbers show as 123.

Answer (score 4):

Founded [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16557)
there is a complement so you **don't have to change the whole code**.

There's such issue in Google's bugtracker: [Arabic numerals in arabic language intead of Hindu-Arabic numeral system](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16557)

If particularly Egypt locale doesn't work due to some customer's issue(I can understand it), then you can format your string to any other western locales. For example:

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","US")); //or "nb","No" - for Norway
 String sDistance = nf.format(distance);
 distanceTextView.setText(String.format(getString(R.string.distance), sDistance));
```

If solution with new `Locale` doesn't work at all, there's an ugly workaround:

```
public String replaceArabicNumbers(String original) {
    return original.replaceAll("١","1")
                    .replaceAll("٢","2")
                    .replaceAll("٣","3")
                    .....;
}
```

(and variations around it with Unicodes matching (U+0661,U+0662,...). See more similar ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java))

**Upd1:**
To avoid calling formatting strings one by one everywhere, I'd suggest to create a tiny Tool method:

```
public final class Tools {

    static NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("en","US"));

    public static String getString(Resources resources, int stringId, Object... formatArgs) {
        if (formatArgs == null || formatArgs.length == 0) {
            return resources.getString(stringId, formatArgs);
        }

        Object[] formattedArgs = new Object[formatArgs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < formatArgs.length; i++) {
            formattedArgs[i] = (formatArgs[i] instanceof Number) ?
                                  numberFormat.format(formatArgs[i]) :
                                  formatArgs[i];
        }
        return resources.getString(stringId, formattedArgs);
    }
}

....

distanceText.setText(Tools.getString(getResources(), R.string.distance, 24));
```

Or to override the default `TextView` and handle it in `setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type)`

```
public class TextViewWithArabicDigits extends TextView {
    public TextViewWithArabicDigits(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TextViewWithArabicDigits(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(replaceArabicNumbers(text), type);
    }

    private String replaceArabicNumbers(CharSequence original) {
        if (original != null) {
            return original.toString().replaceAll("١","1")
                    .replaceAll("٢","2")
                    .replaceAll("٣","3")
                    ....;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I hope, it helps

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the locale for the individual `TextView` or elements that extend it in your app.
 see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextLocale(java.util.Locale) for more information

**UPDATE**
You can use the following method to parse the number to the locale you want

```
public static String nFormate(double d) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(10);
    String st= nf.format(d);
    return st;
}
```

Then you can parse number to double again

Comment: I changed application localization to arabic but when I want to use numbers in my app Like gps location :   Location MyLocation = getLocation.CurrentLocation(this); it's return the result in arabic numbers

Answer (score 0):

The best and easy way to do is keep the number in all string file as it is , in all the localization strings. Or you need to translate each number string into numbers

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, the solution was to concatenate the number variable with an empty string.
For example like this :

```
public void displayPoints(int:points){
    TextView scoreA = findViewById(R.id.score_id);
    scoreA.setText(""+points);
}
```

I used this

```
scoreA.setText(""+points);
```

instead of this

```
scoreA.setText(String.format("%d",points));
```

this will even give you a warning that hardcoded text can not be properly translated to other languages, which exactly what we want here :) .