# How to convert Bengali Unicode numbers?

Tags: java, unicode

How can I convert Bengali Unicode numerical values `(০,১,২,৩,...,৮,৯)` to `(0,1,2,3,...,8,9)` in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316131/convert-string-to-another-locale-in-java)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Character.getNumericValue` to get the integer value associated with a character:

```
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue('০'));
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue('১'));
// etc.
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/yhoqxo)

The advantage over other approaches here is that this works for *any* numeric chars, not just Bengali.

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution subtract the value of `'০'` to the rest, since they are contiguous in the Unicode table, and add `'0'`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] bengaliDigits = {'০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯'};
    for (char bengaliDigit : bengaliDigits) {
        char digit = (char) (bengaliDigit - '০' + '0');
        System.out.print(digit);
    }
}
```

This will print `0123456789`.

Comment: True, but you are printing instead of converting.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
/**
 *
 * Convert a bengali numeral to its arabic equivalent numeral.
 *
 * @param bengaliNumeral bengali numeral to be converted
 *
 * @return the equivalent Arabic numeral
 * @see #bengaliToInt
 */
public static char bengaliToArabic(char bengaliNumeral) {
    return (char) (bengaliNumeral - '০' + '0');
}

public static int bengaliToInt(char bengaliNumeral) {
    return Character.getNumericValue(bengaliNumeral);
}
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/qJ8ddX)

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
System.out.format("bengaliToArabic('১') == %s // char\n", bengaliToArabic('১'));
System.out.format("bengaliToInt('১')    == %s // int\n", bengaliToInt('১'));
```

#### OUTPUT

```
bengaliToArabic('১') == 1 // char
bengaliToInt('১')    == 1 // int
```

Answer (score 3):

Use -
Character.getNumericValue('০').
It will work irrespective of the language because it uses the unicode of the character for conversion

Answer (score 2):

A lot of solutions here suggest to simply subtract the Unicode value for the character `০` to get the numerical value. This works, but will only work if you know for a fact that the number is in fact a Bengali number. There are plenty of other numbers, and Java provides a standardised way to handle this using `Character.getNumericValue()` and `Character.digit()`:

```
String s = "123০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯";
for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
  System.out.println(Character.digit(ch, 10));
}
```

This will work with not only Bengali numbers, but with numbers from all languages.