# SQLite language independent query of numbers

Tags: android, string, sqlite, numbers

I have written an android app for fun that have inner sqlite database after gathering many data using html parser I found my numbers that are saved as
 **text** in database, are written in English language, so doing query in persian that people in my country try will return nothing on numbers

```
String q = "SELECT * FROM studentIDs WHERE field1  LIKE '%"+name+"%' OR field2  LIKE '%"+name+"%'";
```

while doing good on both **field1** that is string ,it won't work on **field2** that number stored as string, how should I perform language independent query on numbers?

I can't change characters from English to other I want support for both languages and I can't change it's type to integer because some records are English name

Sorry about my English and thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should use a `Spinner` and create a custom adapter so you can bind numeric value or persian text with a hidden english value that you will use for your request.

Comment: Let me clear things here: You have two records which their type is String, but you have saved numbers as english characters in them(123), and you query them with persian numbers(۱۲۳), right?

Comment: it's correct persian or any other languages

Comment: @Does the field2 contain only numbers? e.g "1234" or it contains characters too e.g "123ABC12"?

Comment: characters or number not altogether

Comment: So why did you say >"i can't change it's type to integer cause some recored's are english name"? You mean because you already have some data in your database you cannot change its type from `String` to `Integer`?

Comment: data is like f1:9424 f2:name<br> f1:saeid: f2:name

Comment: Can you edit your question and put a simple output of `select * from your_table` , I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my idea is make semi-translator for numbers  first check each char like this to see is it number in any language

```
static boolean  isDigit(char ch)//from java doc 
Determines if the specified character is a digit.
```

then use `getNumericValue(char)`

The nice thing about getNumericValue(char) is that it also works with strings like "٥" and "५" where ٥ and ५ are the digits 5 in Eastern Arabic and Hindi/Sanskrit respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data type is String, it means you can store any character sequence to it(depends on your sqlite encoding config e.g utf8) and Sqlite doesn't care and shouldn't care about it.

You have a simple solution here:

Just write a simple mapper before any query to database:

```
String mapToEn(String query) {
    return query
            .replace('۰', '0')
            .replace('۱', '1')
            .replace('۲', '2')
            .replace('۳', '3')
            .replace('۴', '4')
            .replace('۵', '5')
            .replace('۶', '6')
            .replace('۷', '7')
            .replace('۸', '8')
            .replace('۹', '9');
}
```

And use it on your query or query parameters before executing the query to database:

```
Result query(mapToEn(query));
```

***Edit:***

Since you said

> I can't change it's type to integer cause some recored's are english
>   name

I thought your data in the `field1` is a combination of numbers and characters, now that you clarified it only contains numeric or String data you have another solution.

**Database Schema Migration**

Since your database schema doesn't match your requirements anymore you have to make some changes to it. You need to differentiate the data type you have entered, simply adding two new column as `field_str` and `field_num`.

Basically you should write a database migration which is responsible for converting the `field1` column's data from String to Integer if its an Integer without losing any data, Here are the steps you should do:

1. Add an Integer and a String column to your table respectively `field_num` and `field_str`.
2. Iterate through the table and parse all those Strings in `field1`
   to Integer and insert them into 'field_num`column, and insert the unparseable ones into`field_str` column.
3. change your query accordingly.

Since sqlite does not support column drop, You either have to add a new column to your existing table and leave alone the old data to be there, or You can create a new table and migrate all of your data to the new table:

Here is some hypothetical situation:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE some_table(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
 field1 TEXT,
 field2 TEXT, 
);
sqlite> select * from some_table; 
id          field1      field2
----------  ----------  ------
0           1234         name<br>   
1           bahram       name
```

Now create another table

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE new_some_table(
   ...>  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
   ...>  field_str TEXT, 
   ...>  field_num INTEGER,
   ...>  field2 TEXT,
   ...> ) ;
```

Now copy your data from the old table

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO new_some_table(id, field_str, field2)
   ...> SELECT id, field1, field2, FROM some_table ;

sqlite> INSERT INTO new_some_table(id, field_num)
   ...> SELECT id, field1, FROM some_table WHERE typeof(field1) = "integer" ;
```

Now you can query your table based on what type of data you have.

Consider using an ORM which provides the migration tool, like Google's Room or dbflow.

Comment: @nima_moradi How many numerical characters are there? not too many I guess, you can add more `replace()` calls at the end.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple knowledge all database store data in one file and there data get store as string. It depends on our **Database Driver** that interpret them and convert them into other data type as per **Table schema**.

So, different languages is also stored in database as string. No matter if it is number or character. For each language you have to put language converter.

So idea to make your database usable for your and all other country language is to **Encode and Decode**. convert any country number in English while save into database and vice-versa.

You have to make method for all languages for conversation Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5316164/5432730). Or make your own library class to use it universally. Hope you find this useful.